# установка / проверка битов

Tags: ассемблер

Есть код:

```
        org 8000h
BEGIN:  mov 00h, #60d
        mov 08h, #20d
        mov 10h, #40d
        mov 18h, #50d
        mov 0C0h, #00111111b
        btr 0C0h.3,0
METKA:  jnb 0C0h.3, $
        mov a, 0C0h
        mov c, 0C0h.5
        mov psw.4, c
        mov c, 0C0h.4
        mov psw.3, c
        mov c, 0C0h.1   ;C = Y
        anl c, /0C0h.0  ;C = ^X & Y
        orl c, /0C0h.2  ;C = ^X & Y Y ^Z
        clr 0C0h.6
        jb 0C0h.3, $
        mov 0C0h.7, c
        anl a, #0fh
        rlc a
        mov @R0, a
        inc R0
        ajmp metka
END
```

изначально устанавливаются биты от 0 до 6 в единицу, для разрешения записи в них числа..бит разрешения работы номер 3, если он 0,  то работать нельзя, соответственно, программа сразу работает и перескакивает адрес 32, по которому нужно записывать первое число.

как это исправить?

Comment: постарайтесь, пожалуйста, изложить вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только вам.